# react-testing-library cannot find elements after upgrade to material ui v4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, material-ui, react-testing-library

Using `"react-testing-library": "^4.1.6"`

After upgrading **material-ui** from v3 to v4 `"@material-ui/core": "^4.11.0"` all test cases are failing (using jest as test runner)

Tried to upgrade react-testing-library to multiple higher versions but still same error.
Do not get any errors while executing tests apart from test failures saying:

`Unable to find an element by:...`

All the test cases fail with the following error (unable to find DOM element)

```
  Unable to find an element by: [data-testid="element-name"]

    <body>
      <div>
        <div />
        <div
          class="class-name"
        />
      </div>
    </body>
```

stack trace

```
at Object.getElementError (node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/config.js:34:12)
      at args (node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/query-helpers.js:71:38)
      at getByText (node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/query-helpers.js:54:17)
```

Comment: Hard to guess at the cause when you don't show any of your code.

Comment: @RyanCogswell I know but there isn't any code to show since everything stayed the same, just the version update... what do you suggest I show?

Comment: The simplest possible example (that still reproduces the error) of the code you are testing, the corresponding test code, and showing the full error.

Comment: @RyanCogswell updated the question

Comment: You are now showing the full error, but you still aren't showing an example of the code being tested or the test code.

Comment: @RyanCogswell this would take quite some time to build a useful question, I was trying to see if someone stumbled on a similar error since I haven't been able to find anything meaningful online. I've never seen all tests breaking after updating a single dependency, code works fine when starting the app. Anyways tnx for the help

Comment: @EugenSunic - I've encountered the same problem, specifically with instances of MUI Dialogs. Even if I set `open={true}`, and all props would otherwise render the dialoig, it doesn't show up in the DOM. I've tried upgrading from RTL 9.5 to 10.4 and no solution yet.

Comment: It's actuallty quite easy to find an example. Ideally, we'd need to see the code that has the `data-testid`, then the test case for it. Without that, it's a guessing game.

Without seeing that, I would say the problem is with the `data-testid`, try another query option, like queryByText or queryByRole, depending on the component, data-testid should be used as the last resort + it's possible that material ui is having problem with that.
https://testing-library.com/docs/guide-which-query/ - this might help to understand the queries.